# How to model and divide DDD repository responsibility properly

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a DDD repository for `Employee` entity. Employee will have some borrowed equipment from his employer. Because there will be more employee related records like work reports, wage reports and `Employee` entity could become huge I'm thinking to exclude these related records actions out of `Employee` entity / repository.

I'm not sure but when I try to model actions in `Employee` entity I get something like these:

- getBorrowed**Equipment**s
- return**Equipment**
- borrow**Equipment**
- get**WorkReport**s
- get**WorkReport**Detail
- etc

And these actions names / smell as a work with **another** entity and maybe it could be separated to the another repository. I think it's related to composition concept as is  known in OOP.

**Question:**

What is proper entity / repository structure to work with related records to particular entity? E.g. for use case as "get all borrowed equipments for particular employee"? Or "return one equipment back to the employer"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extract the equipment borrowing into another related Aggregate, having the same ID as the `Employee`. The reasons behind this would be one of the following:

1. The equipment borrowing is from another bounded context that correspond to another domain/subdomain from the real world. Maybe another department is responsible for this?
2. There is low cohesion between Employee's *basic* properties and the equipments that he is borrowing.

In either way, you would want to syncronized an `EmployeeBorroedEquipments` with an `Employee` in some situations. For example, when an `Employee` quits he will not be allowed anymore to borrow equipments. For this you could use a Saga/Process manager.

The same applies to the work reporting.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I have no idea how do you suggest to design such aggregate and related repository. Do you suggest something like this, in repo: `BorrowedItem borrow(EmployeeId id, Item itemToBorrow)` and entity will hold all `BorrowedItem`s with reference to employee id with ID value object? Thanks in advance for clarification / elaborating it in more detail.

Comment: @Artegon you create another Aggregate, i.e. `EmployeeBorrowedItems` having the following properties: employeeId and the list of borrowed items as Value objects or nested entities